# Retain the History of the project when moved to new folder in SVN

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, visualsvn

I had 3 projects with three different .sln files. 
For Ease I combined 3 projects into one by creating empty .sln file. 
I have created the new folder on the server and moved the newly created project(3 merged project) in same repo as the old project reside. 
But my log history has lost. How  can I get the history of the old file into new file.

Comment: Have you tried checking out to a new location, to a specific revision you want?

Comment: I quite don't understand it , So Should I checkout the old project folder ? but tot what location ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have done an `svn move` or `svn copy` or use the "create branch/tag" dialog of TortoiseSVN, rather than just creating a new folder and using Windows commands to move stuff around.

There is no way to manually re-link history after doing things without the appropriate SVN commands. You will need to re-do your move, using SVN commands this time.

However there will be no way to trace the history of 3 different files that have now been combined into 1 file. You will need to abandon that history, or pick one file whose history you want to track and `svn move` that one before overwriting it with your merged file.